# Parsing Kconfig using racc

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to parse [kernel config](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-2.6.35.y.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/Kconfig;h=f942bb713a3d96c2c1e348760a7c3208db519807;hb=HEAD) using racc. Everything was ok until it reached ---help--- part. I'm getting error:

```
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:348:in `on_error':  (Racc::ParseError)
parse error on value "\t  Say yes to build a 64-bit kernel - formerly known as x86_64\n\t  Say no to build a 32-bit kernel - formerly known as i386\n" (T_HELPTEXT)
        from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:99:in `_racc_do_parse_c'
        from /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/racc/parser.rb:99:in `do_parse'
        from zconf.y.racc:536:in `parse'
        from zconf.tab.rb:1168:in `'
```

Tried to fix it for a whole day, but still can't understand where error is. Can you help me?

Racc file - http://pastie.org/1194735

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself, forgot to add T_EOL after T_HELP.