# Lex/Rex and Yacc/Racc files for Kconfig

Tags: ruby, yacc, lex

I would like to parse Linux Kconfig files to create a graph visualization of their relationships. My first thought was to use rex/racc (ruby versions of lex/yacc) to parse the Kconfigs because ruby is my language of choice. I figure there must be lex/yacc files for parsing Kconfigs that I could adapt but I cannot for the life of me find any. Does anyone have any links to these or know of any other ruby-based parser for Kconfigs?

I found [this Stackflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844233/parsing-kconfig-using-racc) but there's no useful links or specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Yacc and Lex files for the Kconfig format in the Linux source tree, in the `scripts/kconfig` directory:

- [scripts/kconfig/parser.y](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kconfig/parser.y)
- [scripts/kconfig/lexer.l](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/kconfig/lexer.l)

Of course, these will not work as-is in Ruby/Racc, but they should be a good starting point.